# ctx.drawImage on a canvas on a different window

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, copy

I have a main window where I draw on a canvas and I need to mirror the drawing to a secondary window containing another identical canvas. Note that this has to work with IE11 (**this very same code works on Firefox flawlessy** but unfortunately I need it on IE11). The drawing must be copied in real time (pixel by pixel).

When I use drawImage on the canvas present on the secondary window I get an error. This is the code I'm using:

```
    var mirrorCanvas = mirrorWindow.myCanvas;
    var mirrorCanvasCtx = mirrorCanvas.getContext('2d');
    var currentCanvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    mirrorCanvasCtx.drawImage(currentCanvas, 0, 0);
```

The error is "SCRIPT5022: Exception thrown and not caught" and the line causing it is "mirrorCanvasCtx.drawImage(currentCanvas, 0, 0);"; if I comment this line, the code works.

So I replaced the canvas with an img and I managed to copy the canvas by using:

```
    var currentCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    mirrorWindow.myImage.src = currentCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

But when I add this code to the drawing routine it's super slow on the main window. This is not gonna work.

Why I get an error on mirrorCanvasCtx.drawImage(currentCanvas, 0, 0);?

This is a screenshot of the windows:

[image]

Comment: they are two separate windows, the first one is opened from a page where you press on a button and with window.open it opens, this window, while loading, uses window.open to create the secondary (mirror) page. I added a screenshot of the windows.

Comment: thank you for clarification

Comment: Your error messages are not very helpful... What is the code at the line it thrown? Note that you should be able to draw the canvas from window1 to window2. IE may be buggy though. Providing a real [MCVE] might help to hrlp you.

Comment: Also, are you sure the second window has loaded when you run the code? Can you test on an other browser? It might more useful message than these.

Comment: update: the code works on Firefox. On IE11 I get an error: "SCRIPT5022: Exception thrown and not caught" and the line causing it is "mirrorCanvasCtx.drawImage(currentCanvas, 0, 0);"; if I comment this line, the code works also on IE11. (I edited the main comment).

Comment: Guys anyone can help me out with this one? I'm stuck, I've tried everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after days of useless attempts I found a simple solution. After realizing that for some reason I can't use drawImage on a canvas that is on a secondary window in IE11, I've tried (as I wrote in the main post) to replace the secondary window's canvas with an image and then update the image with this code:

```
var currentCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
mirrorWindow.myImage.src = currentCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Unfortunately, repeating the .toDataURL method at every single pixel drawn causes serious lag issues. **The solution was to use the setTimeout function with a 10 milliseconds parameter to update the secondary window's picture**:

```
function refresh(){
    mirrorWindow.myImage.src = currentCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    setTimeout("refresh();",10)
}

refresh();
```

So instead of refreshing the image on the secondary window every pixel drawn I just do it every 10ms, and this removes serious lag issues and gives a decent synchronized result.